# CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css3, front-end, ux

Eu já estou a um tempo sem mexer com front-end mas agora estou dando uma olhada em CSS Grid Layout. Após ler os artigos, fiquei com uma dúvida: Existe algum número de colunas padrão para começar ou máximo para o layout? Li uma galera comentando sobre usar 12 colunas, é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Isso talvez seja mais uma questão de design do que de front-end, *mas pensando em como um afeta o outro e na experiência do usuário (UX) e o propósito da aplicação você pode variar bastante entre o números de colunas*, e variar também como o conteúdo é distribuído por elas. Sempre pensando na resposividade.

Veja como o Grid pode varia de acordo com o tamanho de tela do dispositivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*"Isso vai depender de você e do seu projeto. A razão para trabalhar com 12 colunas, que é o formato mais utilizado, é por causa da flexibilidade proporcionada e por ser capaz de dividir o layout uniformemente. Ou seja, você pode dividir 12 por 2,3,4 e ter uma serie de modulações disponíveis (2 x 6 , 3 x 4) e também em várias outras combinações. Se você dividir 12 colunas por 2, vai perceber que consegue ter 6 conjuntos de 2 colunas sem que sobre nenhuma coluna.*

*Mas o número de colunas pode variar de projeto para projeto. Basicamente, quanto maior o número de colunas, (14 ou 21, por ex.) maior o quantidade de possibilidades para dividir o layout. Geralmente esse tipo de Grid é utilizado quando se tem muito conteúdo editorial e o design é projetado com uma largura de 1140px ou mais."*

**Aqui tem um excelente artigo em Português com mais detalhes:** https://brasil.uxdesign.cc/um-guia-completo-sobre-grids-para-design-responsivo-6b192fea0124